# Integrate RestKit pod or source into project that has another framework with AFNetworking baked in

Tags: ios, restkit

I have a framework that has AFNetworking baked into it... I would love to be able to use RestKit but there are obvious duplication problems for the linker because the RestKit source uses AFNetworking too...

Does anyone want to present to me a nice method to allow the two to coexist? Since I can't do much about the other framework I would like to have a walk through of how to get Restkit rockin... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The typical method in the ObjC realm is to distribute your framework using http://cocoapods.org to manage the dependency chain for you (and eliminate potential duplication of something like AFNetworking).

Here's a nice read: http://blog.chariotsolutions.com/2012/07/using-cocoapods-to-manage-private.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Cocoapods

```
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.20.0'
```

Check the following [link](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-via-CocoaPods) for more info

Answer (score 0):

The RestKit framework in turn depends on AFNetworking also. 
So, you don't have to install that separately, just install RestKit using pods like this:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.24.0'
```